# Ubuntu "audit: backlog limit exceeded"

Tags: ubuntu

I noticed that I no longer get any output from a `docker service logs my-service`, even though the service itself still seems to be fine, and I can ssh onto the server without any problems.  Then I tried to open a console to the server from the server provider (not sure what mechanism it uses), but I only see lots of these messages:

```
audit: backlog limit exceeded
```

What is the correct way of dealing with this?  I've searched and could only find [this](https://serverfault.com/q/352281/511760) which relates to CentOS -- mine is an Ubuntu based server -- and in addition my server isn't locking up as such.

Comment: There should be additional messages logged of the form `audit: audit_backlog=Y > audit_backlog_limit=X`. Knowing what `X` is set to currently would be helpful.

Comment: Where would I find those messages?  They don't show in the logs I'm seeing at present.

Comment: Based on RHEL/CentOS I would expect it to be logged along with the message you posted. Either `dmesg` should show it, or it's one of the log files under `/var/log`.